# order by of nested table not taking variable value

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-table

```
   SELECT CAST(MULTISET(SELECT *
                          FROM TABLE(table_a)
                      ORDER BY loc_sort_column DESC
                       ) as table_a_type
               ) 
     INTO table_b
     FROM dual;
```

I have this statement that tosses 1 collection of data into another nested table after sorting it.

The problem I am having is that it is not sorting.  I have a variable loc_sort_column that in this case will be a integer/number between 1 and 11 selecting the column but it is not working.

I have stuck 1 in there and it works fine but it doesn't seem to like the variable that contains 1.

Is this an order of operation or something?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is ordering by a constant. Following [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:868710200346844541):

> you cannot dynamically return a column position, you dynamically
>   returned A CONSTANT, A NUMBER, A CONSTANT VALUE - JUST A VALUE
>
> order by < ordinal position> | < expression>
>
> you are returning an expression - not an ordinal position.

What you can do is to use `DECODE` function to decode column position to real column. Please check my code sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_type FORCE AS OBJECT
(
   col_1 NUMBER
  ,col_2 NUMBER
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_nested_table AS TABLE of my_type;
/
DECLARE
  l_table_a     my_nested_table := my_nested_table();
  l_table_b     my_nested_table := my_nested_table();
  l_sort_column NUMBER := 2;
BEGIN
  l_table_a.extend(100);
  FOR l_i IN 1..l_table_a.COUNT LOOP
    l_table_a(l_i) := my_type(ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM,0), ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM,0));
  END LOOP;

   SELECT CAST(
            MULTISET(
              SELECT *
                FROM TABLE(l_table_a)
               ORDER BY DECODE(l_sort_column, 1, col_1
                                            , 2, col_2) DESC
            ) AS my_nested_table
          ) 
      INTO l_table_b
      FROM dual;  

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_1 col_2');
  FOR l_i IN 1..l_table_b.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_table_b(l_i).col_1 || ' ' || l_table_b(l_i).col_2);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This still is not working in my scenario.  I have realized that since I am trying to introduce values not derived from the statement this could be a dynamic statement and have switched to try using that but still having issues there too

Comment: So what is your scenario? Because it does exactly what you were asked.